# Record in one table unique to a record in another table

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Let me try to make it simple with an example.

I am creating a database with 2 tables, School and Students

School table with 2 columns SchoolID(PK) and Location
Student table with 3 columns StudentID(PK), SchoolID(FK) and Grade

The Student table will have students from all the schools which can be identified by the foreign key SchoolID. The StudentID column will be unique to each student across all schools. Well and good so far.

I need another column in Student table which will be unique only with respect to the foreign key value. Let's call this ID. I need this column to be unique only to each SchoolID. So, If I filter out the students belonging to a particular SchoolID, I shouldn't get 2 students with same ID.

I'm not sure if that's a valid scenario.

Edit:
This is good
[image: This is good]

This is not
[image: This is not]

Comment: Why wouldn't it be valid? If there's a use case requiring this column, it's valid. I don't really understand what you're asking here.

Comment: @GertArnold I need the new column in Student table to be unique only across other students who have the same SchoolID. Does that make sense?

Comment: You're just repeating your question. And I can repeat my answer, why wouldn't it? Only you can decide if it makes sense.

Comment: @GertArnold Sorry about that. Let me put it this way, if I set the new 'ID' column as primary, it won't let 2 students have the same value right? so, I need a key constraint that will allow 2 students having same 'ID' value, but will not allow 2 students with same 'SchoolID' to have same 'ID' value.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm unsure how to enforce that using a key constraint in the database.

Comment: So finally we arrive at your actual question. All you need is a unique index.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with the datamodel. Since you have `StudentID` as primary key in Student-table, this column will always be unique in this table. But it seems like you are trying to create a Student-School table where you can have the same student connected to multiple schools (but no the same school multiple times for one single student). I think you need at least 3 tables:
Student (Pk StudentID)
School (Pk SchoolId)
StudentSchool

The `StudentSchool` table will have two FK-columns: StudentID and SchoolID. To protect from the same student beeing mapped to the same school multiple times you could either have the PK include StudentId and SchoolId or create a Unique constraint.